# Modify dictionary or array inside array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not the greatest at php and trying to find answers are not always easy.

I'm trying to modify a nested dictionary inside a data array

This is the php array and I'm trying to modify contacts_new email whenever it returns an error code that the email already exist

```
    $data_array =  array(
        "is_residential"    =>  "0",
        "lead_source"       =>  "Website",
        "notes"             =>  "This is a test",
        "address"           =>  "123 Fake St",
        "locality"          =>  "FakesVille",
        "state"             =>  "NB",
        "country_iso2"      =>  "CA",
        "zip"               =>  "E8J 1T5",
        "contacts_new"      => [[
            "first_name"    => "John",
            "family_name"   => "Doe",
            "email"         => "fk@this.com",
            "phone"         => "5064522782"
            ]],
    );
```

This is the modified section. My `if` works well but the `$data_array` just returns an error.

```
    if (str_contains($reponse, "Email already in use for another contact.")){
        $data_array['contacts_new'][['email']] = "noemail@email.com;
```

I've tried a different variation of the code.

This will dump all the content with the keys from `contact_new` such as `email` that I need
`echo var_dump($data_array['contacts_new'])`

But this will give me an unidentified array key
`echo var_dump($data_array['contacts_new']['email']`

Comment: `$data_array['contacts_new'][0]['email']` Array of arrays also has keys, in your case keys are numeric.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to check each new contact to see if the email already exist and for each of them replace it with a new value if that is the case. If I'm correct about this, you will need to loop over contacts_new and apply your logic to each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the array as [[]] it will create an array inside an array

The created array will default to being key 0, 1, 2 etc.

You can access it how you wrote the $data_array, like this;

`$data_array['contacts_new'][0]['email']`

But perhaps you meant to only use 1 square bracket?

Or maybe add an additional key instead of allowing it to auto-create a numeric one?